# Point $P$ in parallelogram $ABCD$ is such that $\angle APB+\angle CPD=180^\circ$. Prove $AP\cdot CP+BP\cdot DP=AB\cdot BC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

> $P$ is any point inside a parallelogram $ABCD$ such that $\angle APB +\angle CPD=180^\circ$. Prove that $$AP\cdot CP + BP\cdot DP = AB\cdot BC$$

Sum of areas are equal. Also tried to apply similarity but it didn't worked.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Sum of areas are equal.  Also tried to apply similarity but it didn't worked.

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem for some cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: In general, let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram.  For any point $P$ in the space (not necessarily on the same plane as $ABCD$), we have $$AP\cdot CP+BP\cdot DP \geq AB\cdot BC.$$  The equality holds if and only if $P$ is on the same plane as $ABCD$, $P$ lies inside $ABCD$, and $$\angle APB+\angle CPD=180^\circ.$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $APQD$ be a parallelogram.

Thus, $PBCQ$ is a parallelogram, $\Delta ABP\cong\Delta DCQ$ and $\measuredangle DQC+\measuredangle DPC=180^{\circ},$

which says that $PCQD$ is cyclic.

Id est, by Ptolemy $$DQ\cdot CP+CQ\cdot DP=CD\cdot PQ$$ or
$$AP\cdot CP + BP\cdot DP = AB\cdot BC.$$